# Where's the old footage in Boston Legal S03E18 from?

Tags: boston-legal

In Boston Legal [Series 3, Episode 18, Son of the defender](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0977321/?ref_=ttep_ep18) Denny Crane and others are taken hostage. The hostage taker turns out to be the son of a woman murdered by a man who Denny got off the charges in his first case, along with his father.

The episode is interspersed with footage (as flashbacks) from a black and white television program or film with a person who looks like William Shatner.

Where does this footage come from or was it made for Boston Legal?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's actual footage of Shatner from [***Studio One - The Defender***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0394920/)

> Because Shatner has been around forever and has been a TV and film fixture for so long, footage from his 1957 appearance in the TV pilot The Defender was able to be incorporated into this week's episode.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](http://www.adrants.com/2007/04/boston-legal-shines-with-fifty-year.php)</sup>

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studio_One_(U.S._TV_series)) clarifies

> A third-season episode of the ABC legal drama Boston Legal, "Son of the Defender", used clips from the two-part Studio One episode "The Defender" (February 25 – March 4, 1957), featuring William Shatner as an attorney joining his lawyer father, played by Ralph Bellamy, in the defense of a 19-year-old, played by **Steve McQueen**, who is accused of murder. Utilizing clips of the older show for flashbacks, the Boston Legal episode portrayed Shatner's Studio One character as a young Denny Crane trying his first case alongside his father

PS: I can't find any clarification if this was *deliberate* in that the writers based the episode on *knowing* this old show existed and could be used but I'm still looking.

Answer (score 7):

From

[Bianculli, David. The Platinum Age of Television: From I Love Lucy to The Walking Dead, How TV Became Terrific (pp. 220-221). Knopf Doubleday Publishing Group. Kindle Edition.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01A4ATV2I)

One of his picks for landmarks in the history of legal dramas is *Boston Legal*, and the chapter on this show closes with a mention of this very episode.

> One of the most original Boston Legal episodes—one in which he did work with a co-writer, Phoef Sutton—was 2007’s “Son of the Defender,” in which Denny Crane was forced to recount a murder trial he’d helped argue fifty years earlier, as a young lawyer working alongside his father in the new family firm. For flashbacks, the Boston Legal episode used kinescope footage from Reginald Rose’s two-part “The Defender” episode from CBS’s Studio One—the one where Ralph Bellamy played the father, and a young William Shatner the son. That live telecast was from fifty years earlier and was a uniquely clever use of a very old TV legal drama to tell a completely new story.

I also found it interesting that something similar happened on an earlier Shatner show. The two-part episode "The Menagerie" from *Star Trek* incorporated footage from the original pilot for the show "The Cage". While Shatner didn't have a role in the pilot, Leonard Nimoy played Spock in it, so the episode was focused on his relationship with the earlier Captain of the Enterprise.